# JSON Array and Objects length handled differently in Chrome and Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest, iteration

After a XMLHttpRequest a function iterates over the `.records` JSON, however it only works in either chrome or Internet Explorer, not both. 
The problem is the `.length`  property.

In chrome it works when I do this:

```
 request1.response.records.length
 1438
```

In Internet Explorer I can only access the whole JSON Body, not the values of `.records` and this doesn't work in chrome.

```
request1.response.length 
30158
```

The JSON in Question begins with:

```
"{
  "total":null,
   "records":[{
  "id":"5465464865",
  "parentId": "545465",...
```

Comment: Post your code that calls `JSON.parse()` on the response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like Internet Explorer is not interpreting your response as a Javascript object, while Chrome can infer it and treats the response as JS. I'm not sure if that is your problem, but try to specify the [response type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/response) you expect to receive, like below:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'json'; //check if you have this line, add it if you don't
```

Comment: This seems to be the case indeed, but the responsetype is already set.

Comment: Okay! I just did some search and seems like this is a bug in IE11 (is this the version you are using?): https://github.com/naugtur/xhr/issues/123. I'm not sure how to avoid the bug, maybe you could use `eval('var res = '+request1.response+';')` and work with the evaled `res` variable instead of `request1.response`, but I know that this looks hacky and that eval could be evil. Anyway, just give it a try, maybe it solves your problem in the short term.

Comment: Your answer helped me in finding this workaround: `if (typeof answer === 'string') {
   answer = JSON.parse(answer);
}`

Comment: Great, that's a much better solution than the `eval` approach, thanks for sharing!